# Prepend default option to SelectList - MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to prepend an option to my selectlist something like:

```
<option value="">Select an Option Below</option>
```

**Here is my method that generates the selectlist:**

Not sure where to prepend this option. Thanks

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetBuildingClubs(List<BuildingClub> localClubs, List<BuildingClub> psfyClubs)
{
    var buildingClubList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    IEnumerable<BuildingClub> allBuildingClubs = localClubs.Union(psfyClubs);
    foreach (BuildingClub b in allBuildingClubs)
    {
        buildingClubList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = b.MasterCustomerId,
            Text = b.NewBuildingClubName

        });
    }

    buildingClubList.OrderBy(c => c.Text);
    //Prepend the default option here???
    return buildingClubList;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of adding a default value in your collection, you can do it directly in your view :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedValue, Model.BuildingClubList, "Select an Option Below")
```

A `"Select an Option Below"` with a blank value item will appear in your dropdownlist.

Assuming that your model contains a property called `BuildingClubList` initialized by your `GetBuildingClubs` method.

Comment: I guess this is a better way to do it. This way you don't have to mix your data with UI texts in your controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Insert` method like

```
 buildingClubList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = "",
        Text = "Select an Option Below"

    });
```

or

Add default `SelectListItem` before loop

Answer (score 1):

For future users (I know this is old, but I came across it when looking for a solution myself), if you have an existing SelectList with a single selected value then this helper will give you Add and Prepend methods:-

```
/// <summary>
/// A static helper class providing extension methods to SelectList instances
/// </summary>
public static class SelectListExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the specified value to the select list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selectList">The select list.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
    /// <param name="selected">if set to <c>true</c> [selected].</param>
    /// <returns>The modified/rebuilt select list</returns>
    public static SelectList Add(this SelectList selectList, string value, string text, bool selected = false)
    {
        var itemList = selectList.ToList().FluentAdd(
            new SelectListItem { Value = value, Text = text, Selected = selected }
        );
        return new SelectList(itemList, "Value", "Text");
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Prepends the specified value to the select list.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="selectList">The select list.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
    /// <param name="selected">if set to <c>true</c> [selected].</param>
    /// <returns>The modified/rebuilt select list</returns>
    public static SelectList Prepend(this SelectList selectList, string value, string text, bool selected = false)
    {
        var itemList = selectList.ToList();
        itemList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = value, Text = text, Selected = selected });
        return new SelectList(itemList, "Value", "Text", selectList.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a

```
buildingClubList.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Value = "",
    Text = "Select an Option Below"
});
```

before your foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but when the list gets sorted, the default gets pushed out of the 1st position

Comment: You could add it after you sort your list. Anyway, I guess @Réda Mattar's answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

before entering your foreach loop, add:

```
buildingClubList.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = "",
            Text = "Select an Option Below"

        });
```

after they select something, you'll want to verify it was not this option of course

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but when the list gets sorted, the default gets pushed out of the 1st position

Comment: ah, then Satpal's answer will probably be best

Answer (score 0):

This is old and @RédaMattar's answer is the best/correct one if you want a "prompt" option, but I stumbled on it looking to manually add a valued option to a SelectList (e.g. - an option allowing the client to trigger a "New" action) this seems the cleanest way:

```
 selectList = selectList.Prepend(
                 new SelectListItem { Value = "New", Text = "New", Selected = false }
              );
```